# Ng2 - Unit test on Directive, detectChanges() not working

Tags: angular, unit-testing, directive

My Directive:

```
 @Directive({ selector: '[dynamicStep]' })
export class DynamicStepDirective {

  @Input('dynamicStep') associatedMagnitude: number;

  constructor(private _renderer : Renderer2, public _el: ElementRef) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.setAttribute('1');
  }

  ngOnChanges() {
    this.setAttribute('a');
  }
  setAttribute(value: string) {
    this._renderer.setAttribute(this._el.nativeElement, 'step', value);
  }

}
```

My unit Test:

```
    @Component({
  selector: 'dynamicStep',
  template: '<input type="number" [dynamicStep]="inputMagnitude">'
})
class DynamicStepTestComponent {
  inputMagnitude: number = 1.00;
}

describe('DynamicStep', () => {
  let fixture = null,
    component: DynamicStepTestComponent = null,
    inputEl = null;
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    let config: any = commonConfig;
    config.declarations.push(DynamicStepTestComponent);
    TestBed.configureTestingModule(config).compileComponents();
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(DynamicStepTestComponent);
    component = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    inputEl = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('input'));
  }));

  it('ngOnChanges() should call setAttribute() with \'0.1\' if associatedMagnitude is a number with 1 decimal place', async(() => {
    component.inputMagnitude = 5.3; //should trigger ngOnChanges()
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(inputEl.nativeElement.attributes.getNamedItem('step').value).toEqual('a');
  }));
```

It expects a but it gets 1. I think this is because ngOnChanges() hasn't fired, or the change hasn't propagated to the DOM yet, how can I fix this?

Comment: Were you able to sort this out? Its a full day I'm trying to come up with something

Comment: @LppEdd Hey sorry to hear that! Unfortunately it's so long ago I can't remember :(. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! I did it, finally. The problem in my case was the time it took to re-render the template after calling detectChanges. Using fixture.whenStable callback and calling expect + done inside it did the trick